# XSS vulnerability in p:panel?

Tags: primefaces, xss

I am testing a primefaces (4.0) application for cross site scripting vulnerabilities. Now i found an issue with the p:panel header attribute.

```
<p:panel header="#{post.title}" footer="Date: #{post.date}">
```

The value of the header attribute is data inserted by users. When post.title contains Javascript it gets executed by the browser. For example when post.title is `<script>alert(1)</script>` a popup occurs.

I don't understand why it is not encoded in that case, because I thought when using expression language it is output encoded at any time. Can you help me why there is a XSS vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

We also encountered this issue and filled a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6766

Additionally there has been a discussion about this issue in the PrimeFaces forum:
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34678

As a workaround you can use the panel as follows:

```
  <p:panel>
    <f:facet name="header">
      #{myBean.usersText}
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="footer">
      #{myBean.usersText}                           
    </f:facet>
  </p:panel>
```

---

Please note that ELs are not escaped anytime when displayed to users. It's either the components or the developers responsibility to do that. Most components like *h:outputText* however escape the given input.